# Is there a simple form to get a multiindex dataframe like this (python)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm trying to use pandas to go from this:

| Dates | ASML | ATL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31/12/2021 | 710.4 | 17.6 |
| 03/01/2022 | 706.7 | 17.455 |
| 04/01/2022 | 701.7 | 17.78 |

into:

| Dates | TICKER | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31/12/2021 | ASML | 710.4 |
| 03/01/2022 | ASML | 706.7 |
| 04/01/2022 | ASML | 701.7 |
| 31/12/2021 | ATL | 17.6 |
| 03/01/2022 | ATL | 17.455 |
| 04/01/2022 | ATL | 17.78 |

I could build a loop to go through the table, but I guess there is a simple way.

Thanks in advance for the help,

Steve

Comment: Hello my dude would you mind providing, a little sample of your data so i dont need  to try to build it here. Try using df.head().to_dict(). That oughta be enough

Comment: `df.melt(['Dates'], var_name="TICKER", value_name="PRICE")`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.